# How to create a Text file and transfer it using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to create a doc or text file or simple text using java script/HTML5 that would be circulated to all current logged in users one after the other and the user who has the current write access can write and send file to the next and at the same time every time the doc is updated it should be reflected to all users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
 function WriteToFile(passForm) {

    set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");  
    set s = fso.CreateTextFile("C:\test.txt", True);
    s.writeline("HI");
    s.writeline("Bye");
    s.writeline("-----------------------------");
    s.Close();
 }
  </SCRIPT>

</head>

<body>
<p>To sign up for the Excel workshop please fill out the form below:
</p>
<form onSubmit="WriteToFile(this)">
Type your first name:
<input type="text" name="FirstName" size="20">
<br>Type your last name:
<input type="text" name="LastName" size="20">
<br>
<input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

works only with IE

Answer (score 0):

You could use the HTML5 file reader API

```
<input type="file" id="files" name="files[]" multiple />
<output id="list"></output>

<script>
function handleFileSelect(evt) {
 var files = evt.target.files; // FileList object

 // files is a FileList of File objects. List some properties.
 var output = [];
 for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {
   output.push('<li><strong>', escape(f.name), '</strong> (', f.type || 'n/a', ') - ',
              f.size, ' bytes, last modified: ',
              f.lastModifiedDate ? f.lastModifiedDate.toLocaleDateString() : 'n/a',
              '</li>');
 }
 document.getElementById('list').innerHTML = '<ul>' + output.join('') + '</ul>';
}

document.getElementById('files').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);
```

And you could use the readAsText Method

**FileReader.readAsText(Blob|File, opt_encoding) -** 
The result property will contain the file/blob's data as a text string. By default the string is decoded as 'UTF-8'. Use the optional encoding parameter can specify a different format.

Go to: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/ for more info.